# Julia DataFrame Row data type has been changed?

Tags: dataframe, julia, union

I am not sure since when but actually DataFrame 'Row' data type has changed.

```
■previous
    Row │ id      name     sex      age     ave        
    │   │ Int32  String  String  Int32    Float64                
    │───┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    │⋮ │   ⋮     ⋮       ⋮       ⋮       ⋮
 

■recent   
    Row │ id      name     sex      age     ave     
    │   │ Int32?  String?  String?  Int32?  Float64?               
    │───┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    │⋮ │   ⋮      ⋮        ⋮       ⋮        ⋮
```

You can see all 'Rows' data type are changed to be putting '?' at its tail.
In the previous version, I can get the row data type with  eltype.(eachcol(df)), because they were simply 'Int32','String'.....
But in the recent case, they are Union{Nothing,Int32}, Union{Nothing,String}...., that why eltype.(..) does not give expectation data type alike previous version.
My questions are

1.How can I get the 'Row' data type now alike the previous?
I mean convert(?) 'Union{Nothing,Int32}' to 'Int32' whichever on DataFrame or by eltype()

2.Optionally: Do you know since and why the 'Row' data type has changed?

Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you Ph. Kaminski, Yes that was 'Missing' and nonmissingtype() was effect in it.
But I noticed by this, and wanna know how to pin the column data type.
I mean, in the case of no missing data, DataFrame gives abstract type in their column as 'String', however it gives 'Union' type if there were missing data in it as 'String?'. I would like to lock it as 'String' type. 
Can I do it?

Comment: If there are actual missing values in your column then no you can't have the column type as `String`, it has to be `Union{Missing, String}`. If your column types are `Union{Missing, T` but there aren't any actual missing values you can call `disallowmissing(df)` to turn all `Union{Missing, T}` columns into `T` columns.

Comment: Oh, no way, thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

> Do you know since and why the 'Row' data type has changed?

First, please double check that your data is not `Union{Nothing,Int32}` but `Union{Missing,Int32}`.

Nothing has changed in DataFrames.jl here. Your data reading process might have changed and it now creates columns allowing for `missing` values in them.

> How can I get the 'Row' data type now alike the previous?

If you want to strip the `Missing` part of the element type of column do:

```
nonmissingtype.(eltype.(eachcol(df)))
```